# What is the point of adding and removing the element from Priority Queue in the given dijkstra code?

Tags: java, dijkstra

I was studying Dijkstra algorithm code given at this link -> https://java2blog.com/dijkstra-java/

Can someone explain the following 2 parts of the code?

1) Why are we adding and removing the element from Priority queue when calculate distance is less?

```
if( newDistance < v.getDistance() ) {
    priorityQueue.remove(v);
    v.setDistance(newDistance);
    v.setPredecessor(actualVertex);
    priorityQueue.add(v);
}
```

2) What are we doing in compareTo method and why?

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Vertex otherVertex) {
    return Double.compare(this.distance, otherVertex.getDistance());
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444639/altering-hashcode-of-object-inside-of-hashset-hashmap for the first part. It is similar to this one.

Answer (score 5):

To begin with, this code is bad, since `priorityQueue.remove(v)` requires O(n) time, which defeats the whole purpose of using `PriorityQueue` https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html:

> ... linear time for the remove(Object) ...

2) Dijkstra's algorithm in one phrase: select a non-visited vertex with a *smallest* `distance`. To extract the vertex with a smallest distance, you maintain a priority queue, where you compare vertices by distance (this is what your `compareTo` does). So the vertex which is extracted will be the vertex with the smallest distance.

1) Data structures have some assumptions. If these assumptions are violated, data structures may work incorrectly. In case of `PriorityQueue` the assumption is "for any elements in the queue the result of comparison doesn't change". And, since you compare using `distance`, if you change the `distance`, then the result of comparison may also change, leaving your `PriorityQueue` in potentially invalid state. Therefore, you first remove the element, and only after that change the distance.

Comment: Remark: It is not necessary to remove the object with the „old“ distance from the priority queue. It would destroy performance. Because the queue is sorted, it is sure that the object with the new, shorter distance is visited first. So when the old object is visited, you will find it in the visited list. Testing if an object is in a List, Set, Map, or has a flag set or how you implemented visited will be faster than removing an object from the middle of the queue.

Comment: @ChristianH.Kuhn, true. But it will require more memory, so I prefer another option: use BST-based priority queue (i.e. `TreeSet`, where min is `first()`).

Comment: `TreeSet` doesn't allow different vertices with equal distances. You must modify `compareTo()` to return a +ve / -ve value based on a secondary attribute if the distances are equal.

Answer (score 2):

1) PriorityQueue only evaluates priority when entries are inserted. Just changing the priority on `v` will not cause this evaluation, so it will have no effect.

2) The basic contract for `compareTo` is that it returns 0 iff both instances or considered equal. 1 if this is considered "bigger" -1 if this is considered "smaller". `Double.compare(..)` creates this semantic for a `Double` value.